# Magento customer left join not returning all column from customer table

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, join-table

I wrote the join query with customer table, its only returning both table matched values only,instead of returning all the left table rows.

The Query:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();  
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('review'=>'flrating'),'e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id',array('total_review'=>'COUNT(review.reviewed_user_id)'));

$collection->getSelect()->group('review.reviewed_user_id');  
$collection->getSelect()->order("AVG(review.avg_rating) ASC");
```

Can you suggest me how to return the non-matching left table(customer) rows?

**My expected result is**

[image]

**I am getting**
[image]

Comment: I don'T understand the question. What do you expect and what do you recieve? Can you give a list what you expect and what is not in there please?

Comment: now see the question, i attached the images hope it will better for your understand.

Comment: You know what groupBy means?

Comment: yes, i know . why there have any problem in that above query. if have anything means guide i will rectify and learn better the group by concept .